# SharePoint 2010 Publishing Images

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, publishing-site, publishing-page

SharePoint 2010 - Cannot download or view some image files on the publishing images folder.   Some images opens fine but some does not. There is no error on the logs as well.

Update:

I was able to fix some of the images using `SPweb.ParserEnabled = $false` and then setting it back to `SPWeb.ParserEnabled = $true`. This script fixed some of the issues I was facing.

Now the issue is that I cannot upload any files to the sharepoint. The log says:

> 01/05/2015 13:13:44.11  w3wp.exe (0x2038)        0x0FA8 Document Management Server                Document Management                52od      Medium               MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b7CB0DC2E-3C47-4C0A-9830-A4AF26F088DA%7d&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.     6be24582-4d12-400b-b7da-fb1aa51d6e26
>   01/05/2015 13:13:44.12  w3wp.exe (0x2038)        0x0FA8 SharePoint Foundation General                8e2s       Medium                Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002      6be24582-4d12-400b-b7da-fb1aa51d6e26

The file never gets updated.

I also see this entry in log:

> 01/05/2015 16:18:35.63 OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1B04)   0x0704  SharePoint Server   Database    tzku    Verbose ConnectionString: 'Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Connect Timeout=15'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15  8cf5c031-9213-434e-973f-b9da57fa5583

These errors are popping up everywhere.

Comment: did publish all images? and check if someone checked out your page

Comment: Yeah, the pictures are all published and is not checked out to anyone.. The site freezes if I try to open the file. No one can open any existing pages and and have to reset the iis. (net stop/start w3svc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in case someone has the same issue, uninstalling Security patch KB3013126 fixed the error. The solution was provided by Microsoft Support.